# jquery ajax call async: true vs async:false

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, get, synchronous

In my chrome extension i used jquery library and this is my post ajax request but i am confuse is it synchronous request or asynchronous ?

```
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "https://api.xxx",
            data: { domain: b },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data)
            {
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                .......
                if () 
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
            },
            error: function (data)
            {
                $('.popup').html("test");
            }
        });
        return $ret;
    }
```

if it is synchronous is it enough to add

```
async:true
```

to make it asynchronous?

NB: I have another GET request. thing is POST request is working pretty fine but during get request the response is really slow sometimes i had to make several click or reload to make it work.

Comment: AJAX is, by definition (by default too), asynchronous.

Comment: Does browser freeze during GET request?

Comment: thanks.  @A.Wolff no browser not freeze but when i click on the icon  it shows nothing for 6/10 sec sometimes never shown up but when i reload the page or open a new tab it is working fine !

Comment: @user12 So this has nothing to do with sync request but how fast/slow is the server to respond or maybe you get some error on page, check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> async (default: `true`)
>   By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active

So, there is nothing you need to do to make it asynchronous. Also, it is generally a bad idea to make these sort of calls synchronous anyway.

Comment: It should be noted that this option could be overriden by a global one. I'm not sure what is browser extension global context though

Comment: If you've setup global settings to make AJAX not Async then all bets are off!

Comment: @Jamiec no i havent set anything like that . except what i mentioned in my code.

Comment: Sorry that "you've" was in response to the comment above it. I gathered you hadn't set that. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: i got my answer but i am just confuse if server response is slow is it for my code structure or something else.

Comment: If the response is slow, its probably the server-side code not the javascript

Comment: @Jamiec i get your comment but my previous one was regarding OP is coding a browser extension so he cannot be sure what original page code is doing, that was my point

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Ajax call by itself is asynchronous. Please refer: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/